# Localizations of infinity categories and fibrant replacement

Tags: homotopy-theory, localization, model-categories

In *Higher Topos Theory* by J. Lurie, Def. 5.2.7.2, a localization functor between $\infty$-categories is defined as a functor having a fully faithful right adjoint.

Now, given any $\infty$-category $\mathscr C$, consider a fibrant replacement $\mathscr{C}\to \tilde{\mathscr{C}}$ in the model category of simplicial sets (Kan model structure). The replacement $\tilde{\mathscr C}$  is an infinity-groupoid, hence all of its morphisms are equivalences. So, is it true that we can regard $\tilde{\mathscr{C}}$ as a localization in the previous sense? If so, I have trouble in finding the right adjoint...

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A localization in the sense of Lurie is a [reflective localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective%20subcategory).
In particular, the localized category must be a full subcategory of the original ∞-category.
There are many ∞-categories C such that C̃ is not a full ∞-subcategory of C.
For instance, take C to be the delooping of a monoid that is not a group.

Comment: I see, you are right... so, the case of the fibrant replacement is also not a reflective localization?

Comment: What does "also" refer to?  I was talking about C̃, which is the fibrant replacement of C.

Comment: Of course. I didn't remember that the delooping works as a fibrant replacement, sorry.